# Setting Window Icon SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl2

I've been playing around with SDL2 and have made a very nifty little program!
Now, I'm trying to set my window icon - for the SDL Window. I have the following code in the main function of my program, right after SDL initialization stuff.

```
            SDL_Surface* icon = IMG_Load("assets/system/interface/icon.png");
        SDL_SetWindowIcon(window, icon);
```

However, the topbar icon and the toolbar icon remain the same, default application icon! What could I be doing wrong???

Thanks!

Comment: Does `SDL_GetError` return anything? Is `icon` properly loaded (not `NULL`)?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Yes, 'SDL_GetError' does return something. However, I don't think it's related or that it affects the program in any meaningful way. I cold be wrong, though!   'Couldn't open C:\TIMIDITY\/etc/timidity/freepats.cfg'

Comment: And what about my second question?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I wrote an if statement to check if the surface equaled NULL. According to that, everything loaded properly. So that's not the problem either.

Comment: Image size could be too large maybe? Try another image, sized 128x128 pixels. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228153/using-sdl-setwindowicon-is-not-working-properley

Comment: @Bram Just resized my image to 128*128. No change....

Comment: @Bram I also tried 75*75. No change. Well guess what? Once or twice I'm SURE I saw the icon load in the top corner of the window. However, this was very periodic. Only once every 20 runs of the program, I would say. Also, the icon in the dock (IDK what it's called on windows) never changed.

Comment: Maybe your SDL_Surface is destroyed after setting the icon? Are you sure you keep it around?

Comment: @Bram Well actually, I WAS freeing the surface right after I called the set icon function. When I comment out the free surface line, nothing changes.

Comment: @Bram This is my set icon function which I call right after I build my window: `void setIcon() {
 cout << "ATTEMPTING TO SET ICON" << endl;
 SDL_Delay(1000);
 SDL_Surface* icon = IMG_Load("assets/system/interface/window_icon.png");
 SDL_SetWindowIcon(window, icon);
 if (icon == NULL) {
  cout << "NULL ICON" << endl;
 }
 //SDL_FreeSurface(icon);
 SDL_Delay(1000);
}`

Comment: Try bypassing the file load altogether, by copying the example for SDL_SetWindowIcon() to see if it's the content that stops it from working. https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowIcon

Comment: @Bram Aha! When using the surface provided in that example, the icon displayed the SDL logo! (Which I assume is what that vector graphic is an image of) So yes, it has something to do with the content...

Comment: Haha! I got it working, by editing and resizing my image to get rid of alot blank space surrounding the actual image. When I got rid of all the blank space, it worked! However, the icon only loads in the topbar of the window. Is there another function to change the toolbar (bottom bar) icon? Because the toolbar icon is still the default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So even though my question was never FULLY answered, (I never changed the taskbar icon) I was still able to change the topbar icon.
My problem was simply that the image was sized wrong and had too much transparent space around it. When I deleted the transparent space, everything went perfectly.